# Send matplotlib plot over pymsteams as file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a plot from databricks to MS teams using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512495/sending-matplotlib-image-to-pymsteams-cannot-create-new-tag-pymsteams). While this approach works, I can only send a plot with dimensions 2 inches x 2 inches. Is there a way to increase this limit or send the png file over as an attachment instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For MS teams, images must be at most 1024×1024 or 1 MB. Currently it is not possible to increase the limit.

Comment: Please let us know if you still have further query on this.

Comment: Hi Mamatha-MSFT, thank you for your reply. Is there a way to upload the plot in the files tab in the teams channel?

Comment: Yes. You can upload the plot in the files tab in the teams channel. Please refer to the [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/56.teams-file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

For MS teams, images must be at most 1024×1024 or 1 MB. Currently it is not possible to increase the limit.